# Building ASSIMP with MinGW causes file too big error

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64, assimp

I am building ASSIMP using cmake and mingw-w64 on windows 10 and it gives me "file too big" errors while creating the object code. I tried using MinGW and MinGW-w64 and both give me the same error. I am using the default settings, I configure the project with cmake, generate the makefile and then run mingw32-make. Is there some kind of flag I can set to fix this?

Compiler:

```
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
```

Here is the output:

```
[ 59%] Building CXX object code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/StepFile/StepFileImporter.cpp.obj
[ 60%] Building CXX object code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/StepFile/StepFileGen1.cpp.obj
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe: 
CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\Importer\StepFile\StepFileGen1.cpp.obj: section .xdata$_ZNSt10_Head_baseILy0EPN6Assimp8StepFile29directed_dimensional_locationELb0EE7_M_headERKS4_: 
string table overflow at offset 10000029
C:\Users\ANDREW~1.NOT\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwwseVM.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\ANDREW~1.NOT\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwwseVM.s: Fatal error: can't close CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\Importer\StepFile\StepFileGen1.cpp.obj: File too big
mingw32-make[2]: *** [code\CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\build.make:2485: code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/StepFile/StepFileGen1.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:274: code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:129: all] Error 2
```

EDIT: I was using the master branch of Assimp from github, which has newer experimental features. I downloaded an older release version and I did not get the same errors.

Comment: Guessing: are you trying to build using a 32bit compiler rather than a 64bit one and the file is greater than 2 (or 3.5) GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is fixed by assimp itself https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/2406 Which version do you use?

Comment: I updated from 5.0.1 to 5.2.4 and this issue was resolved.
https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases/tag/v5.2.4

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me :
Go into the CMakeLists.txt and add:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-O3")
```

Then compile with some options off:

```
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS=OFF
make -j4 && make install
```

It worked for 5.0.0-rc1 and 5.0.1 too.